# How to use Linq Aggregate Query to print line sequence number alongwith some data from the List<string>?

Tags: linq

I have a simple List like

```
List<string> Test=new List<string>() {"A","B","C"}
```

I am using a simple Linq.Aggregate as under to get a string from the elements of this List as under:-

```
string Output= Test.Aggregate((First, Next) => First + "\r\n" + Next);
```

This gives me the result like(new line separated):

```
A
B
C
```

However,i want result with a sequence number on each line,ie like this:-

```
1)A
2)B
3)C
```

How do i do this using linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` has an overload that will give you the index of the element to work with so you could do `Select((x,i)=>String.Format("{0}){1}", i+1,x))`. Or in full:

```
string output= Test.Select((x,i)=>String.Format("{0}){1}", i+1,x)).Aggregate((First, Next) => First + "\r\n" + Next);
```

One thing worth mentioning though is that string concatenation in a loop (and in the `Aggregate` counts as in a loop) is generally considered a bad idea for performance reasons. You should consider using alternative methods such as a `StringBuilder`:

```
string output = Test
    .Aggregate (new StringBuilder(), (sb, x) => sb.AppendFormat("{0}){1}\r\n", lineCount++, x))
    .ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `Aggregate` here, just a `Select` to get the index and join the resulting list back together to make a single string, for example:

```
var output = string.Join("\r\n", 
    Test.Select((s, index) => $"{index+1}){s}"));
```

Comment: With the old adage of repeated string concatenation is bad does that apply to making a bunch of strings by concatenating two multiple times. ie do we need to worry about the fact that $"{index+1}){s}" is presumably internally concatenating strings and we are doing this multiple times or is it only when we are creating one huge string by multiple concatenations that we need to worry? I went for a stringbuilder in the aggregate to avoid having to worry about it but wasn't sure if that was overkill...

Comment: @Chris StringBuilder is a good possibility. The `$"..."` method is just syntactic sugar wrapped around `string.Format` so no concatenation there.